# Ubuntu 18.04 Graphics in Details Wrong

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Here is the problem, I got a new PC (Ryzen 5 3600, Nvidia 3060 Ti) these days.And I installed ubuntu 18.04 for it. After that, I installed Nvidia driver, Cuda to train neural network. But in settings ->  details -> Graphics, it still shows llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits) (see in figure screenshot).
[image: .]

So I wonder what should I do to make it show 3050 Ti at Graphics ?
(English is not my native language, so if there are grammar or vocabulary problems in my description, please ignore it.)

Comment: Is something not working as it should? Or does the label just bother you?

Comment: Thanks for comment firstly. My PC runs well in my daily work. But  2 days ago, when I just reboot it, the Nvidia driver disappeared suddenly, so I am worrying about is there any hidden troubles about my driver. I don't want it disappear again when I am doing my work in the future.